# React Native text field inside webview got overlap at last textfield

Tags: android, react-native, webview

in my react native app i have one webview and inside that i have 4 textfield on that so when i focus last text input at that time keyboard is overlapping last text field not scroll automatically below is m code

```
render() {
return (
    <View style={styles.mainView} >
    <WebView 
     ref={r => this.webview = r}
     style={{width:globals.screenWidth, height:globals.screenHeight}}
     bounces={false}
     style={{ flex: 1 }}
     startInLoadingState
     scalesPageToFit
     javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     domStorageEnabled = {true}
     onNavigationStateChange={this.handleNavigationStateChange}
     onLoadStart={() => {
     }}
     onLoadEnd={() => {
     }}
    source={{uri: this.state.url}}
     onError={(error) => this.onError()}
    />
    </View>
);
}
```

So any idea how can i solve this your all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: Can you share the full code, please?

Answer (score 0):

try to use https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view instead of View component.